# Laravel 5 | Route Model Binding not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I'm new to `Laravel 5`.
I am trying to bind my `routes` with `models`.

In My RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);        
    $router->model('messages','App\messages');
}
```

My Controller is : `Message_cont`

My Function is :

```
public function show(Message_cont $id) {
     dd($id);
}
```

My Output is :

```
message_cont {#199 ▼
#middleware: []
#validatesRequestErrorBag: null
}
```

What is wrong with my code...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the show method to pick the appropriate model

```
public function show(\App\messages $messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model's name is `App\messages`, but you are waiting `Message_cont` in `show` method.